# Einstein's mirror in train thought experiment

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, thought-experiment

I'm a bit confused about one of Einstein's thought experiments.

In his experiment, he sits in a train travelling at the speed of light and holds up a mirror. From what I've read and researched, he will see his reflection in the mirror. I don't understand why or how he will. Any explanations would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Technically, the train (or any matter) cannot travel at the speed of light. I think you mean the train is traveling at a "relativistic" speed $v$ which is less than $c$ but close enough to be important for relativistic effects.

Comment: Are you sure he isn't travelling *near* the speed of light? I think according to his theory an object with mass can *approach* the speed of light, but never reach it.

Comment: According to my textbook, it's the speed of light, but they might've just made an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the speed of light is a fundamental quantity and the frame of reference doesn't change its value. The speed of light doesn't follow the newtonian relative motion and that is the very essence of this thought experiment. If the speed of light would have followed the relative motion then the person sitting on the train (travelling with light speed) can never have seen himself in the mirror as the speed of the light would have become $0$ and never would have reached his/her eyes, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Einstein used the theory of Galileo as the basis of his imagination of himself as travelling at the speed of light (C). (the train comes from  different aspect of this and is not relevant to the question being asked).  This theory said that all steady motion is relevant and cannot be detected without reference to an outside point.  But Einstein argued that, using a hand mirror, he should be able to see himself normally even if he were travelling at the speed of light.  This is because if your image disappeared when moving at this speed you could tell you were moving without reference to an outside point.  However, this 'fact' would violate Galileo's principle of relativity.  Einstein then wondered if those observing him from the ground would also see the light move away from his face to the mirror at the speed of light, relative to him.  As speed is distance divided by time in miles per hour, Einstein realised that if the speed of light were fixed, the distance and time would have to be different for those looking at him.  So, by accepting Galileo's relativity principle as his starting point, he had to re-think the other two factors. Hence, he ultimately developed his special theory of relativity.

Answer (score -1):

If you are traveling in vehicle i.e. the train .at faster than the speed of light .so is it's contents the mirror,the light inside the vehicle and yourself. Even the air you are breathing..so as everything on the outside of the train is passing you by faster than speed of light .you are basically sitting still.. therefore allowing you to see yourself in the mirror..it's that simple ..you guys are thinking way to hard for an answer that is right in front of your faces.. it's just like airplane pilots who travel faster than speed of sound talking to each other they can still hear each other just fine because everything going on or being said is also going same speed as they are when traveling...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).